# Can i record all my input in the Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to prevent students cheat programming.
I use Vim to teaching C,but students usually cheat exams with "ctrl-v"

Can i record all my input in the VIM as a log?
or some propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tip for intercepting all key strokes is described at [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_all_keys).

Answer (score 4):

side note: This answers your question, however, if it could prevent your student from cheating, I don't know. Is it allowed to have customized `.vimrc`?  `ctrl-v` is block selection in vim, why this could be used to cheat?

you can start vim with `-w/W {scriptfile}` option:

> All the characters that you type are recorded in the file
>   {scriptout}, until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want to create
>   a script file to be
>                      used with "vim -s" or ":source!".

I guess vimgolf uses this too..